# React render method that depends on asynchronous request and state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn ReactJS and Redux, and have come across a problem that I cannot seem to get over.

I have a React component, that gets data from an asynchronous request.

```
export class MyPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      enableFeature: false,
    }

    this.handleEnableFeatureChange = this.handleEnableFeatureChange.bind(this)
  } 

  componentWillMount () {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData () {
    let token = this.props.token
    this.props.actions.fetchData(token)
  }

  handleEnableFeatureChange (event) {
    this.setState({ enableFeature: event.target.checked })
  }

  render () {
    if (this.props.isFetching) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>Enable Feature
              <input type="checkbox"
                className="form-control"
                checked={this.props.enableFeature}
                onChange={this.handleEnableFeatureChange}
              />
          </label>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

So, my problem now is that, when I change the state of the checkbox, I want to update the state of my data. However, every time I update the state of my data, the react component method `shouldComponentUpdate` kicks in, and uses the current props to render the original data.

I would like to see how such cases are handled in general.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Redux.. read this http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html... If you want to use React Component Events, try returning false until you reach your desired state https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: change this `this.setState({ enableFeature: event.target.checked })` to `this.setState((prevState) => ({ enableFeature: !prevState.enableFeature }))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like the following, i.e.

1. Use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) to assign props.enableFeature to state.enableFeature. From documentation

> **componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props.** If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.
>
> Note that React may call this method even if the props have not changed, so **make sure to compare the current and next values if you only want to handle changes.** This may occur when the parent component causes your component to re-render.
>
> **componentWillReceiveProps() is not invoked if you just call this.setState()**

2. Use this state to load the value of checkbox
3. Manipulate this state (onchange) to update the value of checkbox

Following code can work in your case

```
export class MyPage extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isFetching: React.PropTypes.bool,
    enableFeature: React.PropTypes.bool,
    token: React.PropTypes.string,
    actions: React.PropTypes.shape({
      fetchData: React.PropTypes.func
    })
  };
  
  state = {
    enableFeature: false,
  };

  componentWillMount () {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  /* Assign received prop to state, so that this state can be used in render */
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.isFetching && !nextProps.isFetching) {
      this.state.enableFeature = nextProps.enableFeature;
    }
  }

  fetchData () {
    const { token } = this.props;
    this.props.actions.fetchData(token)
  }

  handleEnableFeatureChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ enableFeature: event.target.checked })
  };

  render () {
    return (<div>
      { this.props.isFetching && "Loading..." }
      { 
        !this.props.isFetching && <label>
          Enable Feature
          <input 
            type="checkbox"
            className="form-control"
            checked={this.state.enableFeature}
            onChange={this.handleEnableFeatureChange}
          />
        </label> 
      }
    </div>);
  }
}
```

**Note:** The above code was not executed, but should work (babel's stage-0 code)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `checked={this.state.enableFeature}`

Comment: I tried that too. But that still does not help.

Basically, when the `render` method is called (it is called multiple times), the checkbox state is set. However, when the `onChange` method is called, it re-renders the component, because `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true, and then it sets the state of the checkbox back to how it originally was. 

A solution could have been a callback method where I could set the component `state` synced to the component `props` when the backend API request was done, to correctly set the checkbox state the first time.